# Is it a good practice to restrict user keypress input, and if not, what is the best method for validating input?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am currently a student finishing up a Visual Basic class, and my professor insists that with anything I turn in, if user input requires an integer then I should restrict all keypress characters to only numbers/backspace/delete. Same with alphabet strings: he wants me to only allow particular characters based on the program's requirements, but to do so using the keypress event.

I was in the process of trying to restrict "first name" and "last name" fields to only allowing letters and the backspace key, and was researching the best way to do this, when I came across a topic that mentioned this being a really bad idea. The response stated that validation should be handled some other was as/after the input is submitted, but not by restricting the user's ability to enter what they want while they type, even if it's wrong (and I'm sorry, I'd link to where this was, but I've been pouring over so many blogs/threads/etc today that it's just gotten buried and lost by now).

At any rate, I thought that it made sense, although what I grasped from his reasoning was simply along the lines of "it really frustrates the user and isn't necessary". Still, I have spent the past few hours really scouring the web trying to find the best way to validate input though a method other than the keypress or text-changed events, and really haven't had any luck whatsoever.

I guess my question is, is restricting user input through the kepress/handled=true/etc generally a bad practice? If so, why? Should I be focused on acquiring a better habit when it comes to user input validation? And if so, what is the best method for ensuring the user is submitting the right type of information?

I just realize that oftentimes I get into habits based off of what a textbook or a particular teacher says, only to realize that it's something that doesn't present the best solution or is outdated, etc. I really want to make sure I start learning the best coding practices as I go, rather than learning bad habits and getting settled into them. Maybe I'm looking too deeply into something really simple, but I was hoping to get some input from those more experienced than me.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: The prof is utterly wrong.  a) Until they press Enter/Ok/Done, there can be nothing wrong with it b) violates rules *1* of the old Win UI guidelines ("the user is in charge"). c) Windows is not set up for keystroke level validation.  It **can** be done but requires too much code repeated over and over d) there are other methods specifically for that, one od the ErrorProvider, and Validate events.  e) often the valid vals for one field depend on an another.  does s/he also want you to enforce entry in a specific order (see 'b').

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of the type of explanation I was looking for. It just seems better to me to allow the user to be in control, and your reasoning helps me understand why. Thanks for naming good events for the job as well. And I don't think he mentioned anything having to be in a particular order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - It's bad practice if it's the only data format validation done. Form-checking on input is great if it's combined with data validation on the back-end.

> I guess my question is, is restricting user input through the kepress/handled=true/etc generally a bad practice? If so, why?

It's bad practice if it is the first and only line of defense. The reason for this is say this system you're building is for a company, and will be there for a while. For now, your form is the only thing passing information in, and it correctly restricts input data to a certain format, and for a while, the system is good.

Now, say it's been quite a while and you don't really remember this system very well (or even moved on and a new employee is working with this system). The company needs to send information to the system through some other fashion (say mobile), so they write up an app that sends user input to the system. Unfortunately they didn't know about the format, and the system breaks in some new and unforeseen way. By this point the system has grown so big nobody really knows where to begin, and debugging this issue is going to cost everyone a lot of money and headaches, every single time someone wants to add to the system.

So essentially, this problem (which happens literally all the time) can be solved with a combination of good documentation and a formal method of communication between system components, including putting a line of defense at every interface.

> Should I be focused on acquiring a better habit when it comes to user input validation? And if so, what is the best method for ensuring the user is submitting the right type of information?

Of course! Best way is practice building such systems (build something fun that you enjoy), one way to go about it is imagining the user is malicious and wants to break your system because the professor will give him money if he can. Find ways to protect the system from malicious (or more likely, ignorant) users.

Edit:
I didn't delve into one of the biggest reasons: Websites with form validation can be completely bypassed by sending your own POST message with whatever data you want. This means web form validation is ONLY a convenience measure, not a security measure.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your very thorough and detailed response. Sorry if I wasn't too clear in my question, but my current issue relates to VB.NET and making Visual Basic applications. Would the same concept of restricting input AND validating another way apply as they would to a web-based form?

Comment: @Trillian Yes, it's a similar concept for most systems (web forms or not), restricting input on the front-end can give a false sense of security. Front-end restriction/validation is almost always only for providing feedback to the user (so it shouldn't be obtrusive, perhaps for the purposes of this assignment it's to teach you rather than to emulate real-world solutions), the back-end server needs to handle validation of data being passed in always.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am also very new to VB.NET, so someone no doubt has a better solution. Here is my example:

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
            If Not Regex.Match(txtLettersOnly.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Enter alpha text only!", "Validation")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Success!", "Validation")
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class
```

This could be left as a click event, or moved to a Sub procedure.

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles         btnValidate.Click
            validateTextBox()
        End Sub

        Private Sub validateTextBox()
            If Not Regex.Match(txtLettersOnly.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success         Then
                MessageBox.Show("Error! Enter alpha text only!", "Validation")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Success!", "Validation")
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

No, never restrict user input. If you want, put an X mark next the field, which user can hover to see the error message (if there is an error). Server-side form validation should happen on submit regardless of how you do the rest.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it wasn't clear, but my question was in regards to Visual Basic/VB.NET rather than web-based applications or forms. Is what you suggest also applicable to VB.NET applications?

Comment: @Trillian: It does not matter. Web and HTML5 in particular set good standards for user experience. I can see no reason why not apply the same in winforms - your users will love you. Use [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) control, or create your own. Regarding server side validation, you can substitute it with business logic layer. Your winform should not validate anything, but instead pass data to the business logic, which validates it and returns any issues, which are then reported to the user.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!